# How did cnosdb serialize the schema in datafusion?

Tags: database, cnosdb, apache-arrow-datafusion

How did cnosdb serialize the schema in datafusion?

```bash
the trait bound sdatafusion: :arrow::datatypes::Schema: Serialize ' is not
satisfied
§'a T
§'a mut T
the following other types implement trait Serialize':
(TO, T1) (TO, T1, T2) (TO, T1, T2, Т3)
(то, Т1, Т2, Т3, ТЦ)
(То, Т1, Т2, Т3, ТЦ, Т5)
and 143 others (rust E0277)
```